# Is it possible to only detect BLE Beacons if in ultra short distance React Native? (50-100cm)

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I know at least on iOS it's possible to know how far away an iBeacon is. However, I'm not sure about Android, and I'm not sure if there is any way to do this in React Native. I'm also not completely aware of the terminology. `Ranging` is a layman would think as scanning. Is there something I'm missing for distance? I can't find any information in existing repositories like react-native-beacons-manager

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's more like a distance "estimate" than a "measurement", so it might be hard or impossible to reliably filter out devices with tens of centimeters accuracy. Anyway akatz's answer is correct: the distance is estimated based on the received signal strength (RSSI) and a calibrated signal strength at 1 meter distance (TxPower) and TxPower is part of the iBeacon advertisement package. It's possible to find info about the iBeacon advertisement package format and try this out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe iBeacon distance measurements work by doing some calculations based on the received and transmitted power. The received power (RSSI) is returned by the local controller in some form, and the transmitted power is integrated into the iBeacon header. This is a proprietary format for devices conforming to iBeacon, it's not part of the Bluetooth Low-Energy specification.